# d3.js hexbin - adapt to threshold scale

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm working with a high-n data set and am using the basic hexbin framework identical to:

https://blockbuilder.org/mbostock/4248145

After running the visual I notice I'm getting several hexagons that are pure black. After adjusting the domain to:

```
var colorScale = d3.scaleSequential(d3.interpolateLab("#fff", "#95b3d7"))
    .domain([0, 1000]);
```

I still got a few black hexagons, and the other hexagons became extremely close to white to the point where they are barely visible. At this point I also noticed that I struggled to explain the color progression, which led me to be unable to create an accompanying color scale/legend to explain what each hue represents in terms of binned data points. All things considered, I'd like to pre-determine the colors. That is to say, I want to be able to configure the color for hexagons based on how many points fall inside. For instance: <10 points:'blue', >100 points:'steelblue', >1000 points:'gray'.

### Question

How can I implement a threshold color scale with the above hexbin block?